# Run service in its own ip netns namespace on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, systemd, ip, transmission

I used to run services in 14.04 by executing

```
ip netns exec namespacename service start servicename
```

But I realized that this doesnt work anymore on 16.04. The service starts in normal namespace.

I tried to edit /lib/systemd/system/servicename.service file to use namespace but it was not successful. First problem was that the program was executed with its own user who doesn't have access to namespaces. I changed it to run the program as root then use sudo in ExecStart but for some reason service control never came back to command prompt.

Any ideas on how to accomplish a service to automatically and permanently run inside a namespace every time it is restarted on Ubuntu 16.04 ?

If it matters the service in question is transmission-daemon

UPDATE:

I managed to get it working with the following .service file. In the file 'vpn' is the name of the namespace. My problem was setting the wrong `Type` for the service. I still feel that this solution is not the best solution. If you have a better way, please tell!

```
[Unit]
Description=Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'exec /sbin/ip netns exec vpn /usr/bin/sudo -u debian-transmission /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error --config-dir /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info'
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I am not abel to use `exec` in that line: `setting the network namespace "nsben1" failed: Operation not permitted`. I did try with `/usr/bin/sudo` but then it fails because `debian-transmission` is not in sudoers file. Did you add it?

Comment: It does not have to be. Your problem is not related to `sudo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently found in man systemd.exec(5)

```
PrivateNetwork=
           Takes a boolean argument. If true, sets up a new network namespace for the executed processes and configures only the loopback network device
           "lo" inside it. No other network devices will be available to the executed process. This is useful to turn off network access by the executed
           process. Defaults to false. It is possible to run two or more units within the same private network namespace by using the JoinsNamespaceOf=
           directive, see systemd.unit(5) for details. Note that this option will disconnect all socket families from the host, this includes AF_NETLINK
           and AF_UNIX. The latter has the effect that AF_UNIX sockets in the abstract socket namespace will become unavailable to the processes
           (however, those located in the file system will continue to be accessible).
```

Comment: Please add more information than a simple copy from the documentation - namely how to use this parameter in the context of the question.

Comment: I think the answer is quite good. I can go and read systemd.exec(5) for more information myself (which I did). I will try it next time I setup a service this way. But for now I am setting the answer as correct (unless somebody comes upw ith a better answer). Perhaps link to online documentation would be a nice touch : http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man5/systemd.unit.5.html

Answer (score 0):

With `systemd`, you can run a service in a network namespace by adding a **`NetworkNamespacePath=`** line to the service's `.service` file.

**`NetworkNamespacePath=`** is available as of Ubuntu 22.04 and Systemd 249.  (I do not know exactly when this feature was first introduced.)

From `man 5 systemd.exec`:

```
   NetworkNamespacePath=
       Takes an absolute file system path refererring to a Linux network
       namespace pseudo-file (i.e. a file like /proc/$PID/ns/net or a bind
       mount or symlink to one). When set the invoked processes are added
       to the network namespace referenced by that path. The path has to
       point to a valid namespace file at the moment the processes are
       forked off. If this option is used PrivateNetwork= has no effect.
       If this option is used together with JoinsNamespaceOf= then it only
       has an effect if this unit is started before any of the listed
       units that have PrivateNetwork= or NetworkNamespacePath=
       configured, as otherwise the network namespace of those units is
       reused.

       When this option is used on a socket unit any sockets bound on
       behalf of this unit will be bound within the specified network
       namespace.

       This option is only available for system services and is not
       supported for services running in per-user instances of the service
       manager.
```

As of Ubuntu 23.04 and System 252:

```
       This option is only available for system services, or for services
       running in per-user instances of the service manager when
       PrivateUsers= is enabled.
```